# Change listview label value

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am a novice in Xamarin forms.

I would like to change my listview label value when I click on the Label "OK"

Here is my Xaml:

```
            <ListView x:Name="TestList" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell >                           
                            <StackLayout >
                                <Label TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding  ValueAnswer}"  />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

            <Label Text="OK" >
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnResultTest"  />
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
```

Here is my code:

```
List<MyWords> myWords = mywordsdatabase.GetListAnswer();
 List<TestModel> ListWordsTest = new List<TestModel>();
            foreach (MyWords w in myWords)
            {

                var testmodel = new TestModel
                {

                    ValueAnswer = "A"

                };

                ListWordsTest.Add(testmodel);

            }

            TestList.ItemsSource = ListWordsTest;
```

I would like to change my label value to "B" by selecting item, When I click on "Ok" Label.

I cannot see How to make it.

Here my little step for the "OK" Label :

```
public void OnResultTest(object sender, EventArgs args) {         

        }
```

If you have a better solution. I will take

Comment: To be clear, you want to change the value of the clicked label to ```B```?

Comment: Yes, I would like to change the value  on the cliqued label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab the label that was clicked from the `sender` that's passed into `OnResultTest`. Once you get the sender, then you can grab your class via `DataContext`.

```
public void OnResultTest(object sender, EventArgs args) {         
    var items =TestList.ItemsSource as List<TestModel>;
    if (items!= null) 
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            item.ValueAnswer = "B";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks What if I would like to change all the label value to "B" when I click on "Ok" Label?

Comment: Then you would loop through your ```TestList.ItemsSource``` and set ```ValueAnswer``` to ```B```.

Comment: How to set the value please, I do not know the proprety

Comment: Is the question how to change the value of the clicked item or is it how to change the values of all of your items?

Comment: I would like to change the value of all by loop  in listview

Comment: revised my answer.